# Programmatically find interface for route to specific host

Tags: c, routes

I would like to programmatically determine which Ethernet interface packets to a given remote IP will be routed through.

[This question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/531751/find-interface-for-route-to-specific-host) says the route can be found out via the command line like:

```
# ip route show to match 8.8.8.8
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
```

I'd like to find an equivalent way to do that in either C or C++.  I've done a lot of searching but haven't found anything suitable. Any suggestions?

**EDIT I**

Following the suggestion from [Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje), I tried the code below. However, it always returns 0.0.0.0 as the local address.

```
/*
  g++ -g -O0 getPortForAddr.cpp -o getPortForAddr
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("missing parameter\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    const char *ipAddrStr = argv[1];

    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Socket failed");
        exit(2);
    }

    // Try bind - doesn't work
    /*
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(1505);
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(3);
    }
    */

    addrinfo hints;
    addrinfo *remAddrInfo;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_family   = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    int rc = 0;

    if ((rc = getaddrinfo(ipAddrStr, 0, &hints, &remAddrInfo)) != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get address info:" << gai_strerror(rc) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in remoteAddr = *(struct sockaddr_in *)remAddrInfo->ai_addr;

    printf("Connect to %s\n", inet_ntoa(remoteAddr.sin_addr));
    if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &remoteAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != 0)
    {
        perror("Connect failed: ");
        exit(3);
    }
    printf("connected\n");

    // try sending some junk
    ssize_t bytesSent = send(fd, "abcd", 4, 0);
    if (bytesSent == -1)
    {
        perror("send failed; ");
        exit(3);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in localAddr;
    memset(&localAddr, 0, sizeof(localAddr));

    socklen_t localAddrLen = 0;

    if (getsockname(fd, (sockaddr *)&localAddr, &localAddrLen) != 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to get local name: ");
        exit(3);
    }

    const char *ourAddr = inet_ntoa(localAddr.sin_addr);
    printf("OUR ADDRESS IS %s\n", ourAddr);

}
```

Comment: Apart from querying the routing machinery yourself, have you tried the trick of setting up a UDP socket to the destination and getting the local address?

Comment: Good idea.  Would that work if the destination host did not actually exist? So I could still find the route/interface to the destination subnet...

Comment: `ip route show` shows the rule. I find `ip route get 8.8.8.8` simpler.

Comment: If it is a valid IP, your system can calculate a route to it. It is only when sending a packet that you receive "IP unreachable" errors.

Comment: why don't you simply see the "ip" source code? It will answer all of your questions

Comment: *it always returns 0.0.0.0 as the local address.*  You should probably be using `struct sockaddr_storage` instead of `struct sockaddr_in` for `localAddr`.  See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html#tag_13_61  Using TCP instead of UDP would probably work better, too, as long as there's a TCP port you can connect to.

Answer (score 1):

The `iproute2` package, which includes the `ip` command, uses the [`netlink`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) linux kernel interface. For getting routing information, the `NETLINK_ROUTE` protocol family needs to be selected. More information about `NETLINK_ROUTE` sockets is available under the [`rtnetlink`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) keyword.

If a higher level api is needed, there is also the [`libnetlink`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libnetlink.3.html) library, which is actually also part of the `iproute2` package.

Answer (score 1):

True samurai way is use of NETLINK socket (or libnl), one could use ip utility sources as a reference. Much simpler way is to parse command line output, for example:

```
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct route {
    struct in_addr dst;
    struct in_addr src;
    struct in_addr via;
    char dev[IFNAMSIZ];
};

void get_substr(char * dst, const char * src, size_t len)
{
    memset(dst, 0, sizeof len);
    for (int i = 0; i < IFNAMSIZ; i++) {
        if (isspace(src[i]))
            break;
        dst[i] = src[i];
    }
}


int get_default_route_ipv4(const struct in_addr * addr, struct route * r)
{
    char cmd[32+INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char addr_str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, (const void*)addr, addr_str, sizeof addr_str);
    snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "ip route get %s", addr_str);

    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe)
        return -1;

    char buffer[1024];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);

    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pipe);
    pclose(pipe);

    memset(r, 0, sizeof(struct route));
    memcpy(&r->dst, addr, sizeof(struct in_addr));

    char str[32];
    char *tmp = strstr(buffer, "via ");
    get_substr(str, &tmp[4], sizeof(str));

    if (!inet_pton(AF_INET, str, &r->via))
        return -2;

    tmp = strstr(buffer, "src ");
    get_substr(str, &tmp[4], sizeof(str));
    if (!inet_pton(AF_INET, str, &r->src))
        return -3;

    tmp = strstr(buffer, "dev ");
    get_substr(r->dev, &tmp[4], IFNAMSIZ);

    return 0;
}
```